# How to create a widget test that uses go_router's StatefulNavigationShell

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, flutter-navigation, statefulwidget, flutter-go-router

I'm trying to write a widget test for a screen that uses [go_router's](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) `StatefulNavigationShell`, but I'm having trouble mocking the router and getting the expected results.

This is the screen that uses `StatefulNavigationShell` and I want to do a widget test

```
class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
const MainScreen({
    required this.navigationShell,
    super.key,
});

final StatefulNavigationShell navigationShell;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: navigationShell,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CustomNavBar(
        navigationShell: navigationShell,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

For additional context this is an [example](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/example/lib/stateful_shell_route.dart) of how I implement `StatefulNavigationShell` in my project